# How to compute the volume of the intersection of two cylinders

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I have this problem:

> Calculate the volume delimited by $x² + y² = 1$ and $x² + z² = 1$.

I know I have two cylinders, but I can`t find any numeric solution. :(

Any tips on how to get the correct answer?

Thank you!

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: What are the cross-sections if you slice perpendicular to the $x$-axis?

Answer (score 1):

You have the Steinmetz Solid.

$\hskip 2.1 in$[image]

There is symmetry across the planes $x = 0, z = y, z = -y, z = 0, y = 0$

Use that to your advantage.

$$16\int_0^1\int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2}\int_0^y \ dz\ dy\ dx$$

Comment: This is one problem that's actually quite simple with single integration.

Comment: Maybe, it is just how my brain is wired, but this is the approach that is easiest for me to visualize.   Indeed, I in your answer, we get to the same place quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have some working to go with the above answer if that helps make it a bit clearer.

[working](https://ibb.co/jMbWb6t)